# Multiple remote upload server to server

Tags: php, html, css, nginx, nginx-location

I want to make a small script allowing to upload multiple files from one server to another. The problem is when I add more than 100 URLs it corrupts the files.

Any way to do it cleaner so files should not be corrupted.

Here is the script:

```
// Check if form has been submitted
if(@$_POST['submit']){
ini_set("max_execution_time", 0);  // no time-outs!
ignore_user_abort(true);   // Continue downloading even after user closes the browser.
// URLS -- One on each line
$URL = $_POST['url'];
// Relative path to Save downloaded images
// Default is "downloads"
// Make sure that it is writable (chmoded correctly)
$folder = $_POST['folder']; 
// Check if User has provided a local folder
if (!$folder || !isset($folder)){
// Generate error if left blank by user.
die ("Please specify local folder name");
}
// Split all URLS into an array
$urls = split("\n", $URL);
// Remove Carriage Returns (useful for Windows-based browsers)
$urls = str_replace("\r", "", $urls);
$mh = curl_multi_init();
foreach ($urls as $i => $url) {
$path = pathinfo($url);
$g=$folder . "/" . $path["basename"] ;
// Check if file already exists on local folder.
if(file_exists($g)){
// If exists, delete the file so it always contains the latest update. 
unlink($g) or die("Unable to delete existing '$g'!");
}
// Update the user of what's going on
echo "$i) Downloading: from <b>$url</b> to <a href=\"$g\"><b>$g</b></a><br />";
if(!is_file($g)){
$conn[$i]=curl_init($url);
$fp[$i]=fopen ($g, "w");
curl_setopt ($conn[$i], CURLOPT_FILE, $fp[$i]);
curl_setopt ($conn[$i], CURLOPT_HEADER ,0);
// curl_setopt($conn[$i],CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,1000);
curl_multi_add_handle ($mh,$conn[$i]);
}
}
do {
$n=curl_multi_exec($mh,$active);
}
while ($active);
foreach ($urls as $i => $url) {
curl_multi_remove_handle($mh,$conn[$i]);
curl_close($conn[$i]);
fclose ($fp[$i]);
}
curl_multi_close($mh);
} // task closed
?>
<br />
<br />
<fieldset>
<legend>
<label for="url">Server to Server Upload Script</label>
</legend>
<form method=POST>
<label for="url">Insert Files URL, One Per Line: </label><br />
<textarea rows=15 cols=75 id="url" name="url"><?= $URL ?></textarea><br />
<label for="folder">Folder Name: </label><input type=text id="folder" name="folder" value="uploads"/>
<input type=submit name="submit" value="Start Uploading Files!" />
</form>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: In what way does it corrupt the files? What is the contents of the "corrupted" files?

Comment: files are JPG images

Comment: And what is the content of the corrupted images? (You can open them in a text editor). I suspect there might be some error response there from the target site.

Comment: extension and name remain the same but size gone to 0kb, and there is nothing in it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the site you're downloading from is rate-limiting your script. Your  script probably creates more requests per minute than allowed, that's why the latter requests come empty.

To fix this you might want to add another cURL family function, specifically designed for your use case: [curl_multi_select](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-select.php).
It "blocks [execution flow] until there is activity on any of the curl_multi connections" (or timeout is reached).

You could try to use it like this:

```
do {
    if (curl_multi_select($mh, 0.25) == -1) {
        usleep(100);
    }

    $n = curl_multi_exec($mh, $active);
}
while ($active);
```

Comment: added this section and not working on if i add up to even 1000 images url